# Connect client object model to https url

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services

I am trying to connect to a remote sharepoint site through "https" Url using client object model but I am getting the following error:

The underlying connection was closed Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Which version of the client object model - EMCAScript (JavaScript) or the .NET managed client object model?

Comment: .net managed client object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/10/19/working-with-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-on-an-ssl-enabled-site.aspx

**UPDATE**:
So you doesn't work in the browser context. As I understand these things when your code works in the browser context and on the SSL-enabled page the browser automatically add a certificate to each your request because for SSL to work the both sides (the client and the server) need to use a certificate. If you create a request to SSL-enabled resource manually outside the browser you need to supply the certificate youself. The *.cer file is the certificate saved to file. You can use simple self-signed certificate. There are several [tools](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate.html) to create such a certificate. 
The code example shows how to add a certificate from the *.cer file to each your request from the managed client object model in SharePoint.

Comment: what does it mean from the above url: (where it has this)

 X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(@"d:\test.cer");

Comment: Let's accurate the details - what version of client object model do you use? Javascript? Silverlight? Managed?

Comment: Managed one I am using.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I see... can you tell me any tool to make certificate?

Comment: an overview: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate.html. how to do it on IIS7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127%28WS.10%29.aspx (then you can export such a certificate in *.cer file and use).