# Is it possible to use https with Client Object Model in Silverlight

Tags: client-object-model, silverlight, https

I found here this QA: [Connect client object model to https url](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30337/connect-client-object-model-to-https-url) which mentions [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/10/19/working-with-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-on-an-ssl-enabled-site.aspx) how to do it in full .NET client object model.

That would be great if the class `ServicePointManager` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx)) would be in Silverlight DLLs, but it is not.

Is there any other approach?